# Busqeuda en subdocumentos en Mongoose

Tags: nodejs, mongoose

Tengo los siguientes esquemas:

```
let CollaborationSchema = new Schema({

    role:{
        type: String,
        required: [true, "El rol es requerido"],
        default: "USER"
    },

    company: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Company',
        required: [true, "La compania es requerida"]
    },

    area:{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Subsudiary'
    },
    
    state:{
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }

})

let userSchema = new Schema({

    name:{
        type: String,
        unique: false,
        required: [true, 'El nombre es requerido']
    },

    collaborations: {
        type: [CollaborationSchema],
        required: [true, "La colaboracion es requerida"]
    }

})
```

Quiero obtener si un usuario es colaborador en una compania. Yo intente realizar la busqueda de las siguientes formas:

```
User.find({_id: req.body.user, 'colaborations.company': req.body.company})

User.aggregate({ $match: 
  {
     $and:[
       {_id: req.body.user},
       {'collaborations.company':mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.company)}
     ]
  }
})
```

Ambas formas no me funcionaron, me gustaria saber como puedo resolver esta busqueda directamente en la base de datos, si tener que hacer un find y despues buscar en el servidor si pertenece o no, a la compania.

Comment: Suponiendo que los valores `req.body.user` y `req.body.company` contienen `_id`'s válidos, la primera consulta que muestras (usando `find()`) debería funcionar, sin embargo veo un error de tipeo en la misma: tienes establecido en tu esquema el campo `collaborations` (doble letra *ele*), en cambio en la consulta colocas una sola letra *ele*: `User.find({_id: req.body.user, 'colaborations.company': req.body.company})`. Por favor revisa, ya que esto provoca que no se encuentren documentos. Saludos

Comment: Gracias @MauricioContreras era un problema de tipeo!